# Using preg_replace pattern to clean a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to use php preg_replace to **remove** (note that i want them removed, so i dont want to use htmlentities)

I want to allow the charecters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the special chars "@_." only

Comment: Well, what's stopping you?

Comment: Good question @NiettheDarkAbsol, other then the original "question".

Comment: i think @Niet is saying what have you tried so far?  You can't come here and ask for homework solution or work related solution without even trying it first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straight-forward:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.]+/', '', $string);
```

In simple English: Replace one or more occurrences of anything that's not an alphabet, number or the symbol `@`, `.`, with nothing.

**Autopsy:**

- `/` - starting delimiter
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9@.]` - a character class

  - `^` - used to negate the character class
  - `a-zA-Z0-9` - alphabets or numbers
  - `@` - literal character `@`
  - `.` - literal character `.`
- `+` - match the previous quantity one or more times
- `/` ending delimiter

Comment: Use of `\w` is not a good idea. "A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w." [Source](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I agree it's not a good idea. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Amal and Niet. Exatly what i needed.